# Puppeteer timeout error while using waitForSelector()

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://youtube.com");
  await page.type("#search", "Fleetwood Mac Dreams");
  await page.click("button#search-icon-legacy");
  await page.waitForSelector("ytd-thumbnail.ytd-video-renderer");
  await page.screenshot({ path: "youtube_fm_dreams_list.png" });
  const videos = await page.$$("ytd-thumbnail.ytd-video-renderer");
  await videos[2].click();
  await page.waitForSelector(".html5-video-container");
  await page.screenshot({ path: screenshot });
  await browser.close();
  console.log("See screenshot: " + screenshot);
})();
```

It's simple code that I picked up from tabnine. But I'm getting error on waitForSelector line. I'm trying to find a way to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`waitForSelector` is timing out because the way your code is executing, it never waits for search input to load.

I tried your code with `headless: false` setting and was able to produce the issue.

Check out the changes I made below, it now seems to work

```
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false }); // <-- You can remove headless: flase if u like good for debugging
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 800 }); // <-- Not needed if not using headless: flase
  await page.goto('https://youtube.com', {
    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',  // <-- good practice to wait for page to fully load 
  });

  await page.waitForSelector('input[id="search"]', { timeout: 5000 });

  const input = await page.$('input[id="search"]');
  await input.type('Fleetwood Mac Dreams');

  await page.click('button#search-icon-legacy');
  await page.waitForSelector('ytd-thumbnail.ytd-video-renderer');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'youtube_fm_dreams_list.png' });

  const videos = await page.$$('ytd-thumbnail.ytd-video-renderer');
  await videos[2].click();
  await page.waitForSelector('.html5-video-container');
  await page.screenshot({ path: 'youtube_fm_dreams_list_1.png' }); // <-- You can change the path accordingly
  await browser.close();
})();
```

With this I get 2 screenshots

[image: First Screenshot]

[image: Second Screenshot]

Second screenshot will always be black, you probably need to give a timeout since it's taking screenshot as soon as page loads.

Comment: When click triggers navigation, as it does here, it seems best to [`waitForNavigation`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) rather than a selector and using a nasty timeout that's likely to fail or cause undue latency. You could also use `waitForFunction` and run a predicate that there's something happening in the youtube player screen.

Comment: Definitely room for improvement, I will come back and update it after I finish my work. Quickly whipped up this example so that it's at least in a bit of working state. You are more than welcome to make an edit if you like.

Comment: Tried this (in  a different project), saw the element show on the page but this it still times out.